# Why is this html code slanted?

Tags: html

Here is the HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>bob is a big fat baby</title>
</head>
</body>
this is my first webpage
<h1>this is u are bob baby<h1> 

        <h2>how exciting<h2> 
        <ol> 
        <ol>bob is a big fat baby<ol> 
        <ol> he really needs a life<ol> 
        <p>spinz.io the very fun game<p> 
        <p><a href="spinz.io</a></p>  

        spinz.io a very fun game  
        <p> please be honest and put in the box yes or no if u are bob baby or not <p>
```

What is the prbolem in this? When I tried it, all of the text was slanted.
Also, there was no text box. 
If there are any other problems, let me know.

Comment: What do you mean slanted?

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your above code is **riddled** with syntax errors. Please read up on the [**basics of HTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics), and ensure that you follow the required HTML structure in order for your code to display output correctly. You can validate that your code is correct with the [**W3 Markup Validator**](https://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code is likely slanted because the HTML parser is getting confused. This is because your code contains **invalid markup**. You can read up on the [**basics of HTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics) to learn the required HTML structure, and you can validate that your code correctly follows the structure with the [**W3 Markup Validator**](https://validator.w3.org).

Here's a short list of some of the things wrong with the above code:

1. `!DOCTYPE html` should have a space rather than a dot.
2. `</body>` should be `<body>` -- the slash denotes that you are **closing** the tag, and you haven't opened `<body>` yet.
3. You need to **close** (nearly) all tags such as `<h1></h1>`.
4. When linking to an external resource (or website), you need to preface the link with the protocol. In this case, that's `http://www` to link to the full [spinz.io](http://www.spinz.io) with `http://www.spinz.io`.
5. You need to close both `</body>` and `</html>`.

To help get you started, here's the above code with correct markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>bob is a big fat baby</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>this is my first webpage</h1>
  <h2>this is u are bob baby</h2>
  <h2>how exciting</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>bob is a big fat baby</li>
    <li>he really needs a life</li>
    <li>spinz.io the very fun game - <a href="http://www.spinz.io">spinz.io</a></li>
  </ol>
  <p>please be honest and put in the box yes or no if u are bob baby or not</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)